Subtitle word scaling with ASS file causing line shifting
0
I'm trying to make my subtitles scale one word at a time, but I'm running into an issue with the whole line shifting. Is there a way I can scale a word, and make the other words not move sue to the scale effect? Here is the ASS File
[Script Info]
ScriptType: v4.00+
PlayResX: 384
PlayResY: 288
ScaledBorderAndShadow: yes
[V4+ Styles]
Format: Name, Fontname, Fontsize, PrimaryColour, SecondaryColour, OutlineColour, 
BackColour, Bold, Italic, Underline, StrikeOut, ScaleX, ScaleY, Spacing, Angle, 
BorderStyle, Outline, Shadow, Alignment, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Encoding
Style: Default,Arial,18,&H00FFFFFF,&H00FFFFFF,&H00000000,&HFF000000,-1,0,0,0,100,100,0,0,3,1,0.6,5,10,10,10,0
[Events]
Format: Layer, Start, End, Style, Name, MarginL, MarginR, MarginV, Effect, Text
Dialogue: 0,0:00:0.00,0:00:1.00,Default,,0,0,0,,{\an5\pos(192,144)\alpha&HFF&}And so my fellow Americans,
Dialogue: 0,0:00:0.00,0:00:02.50,Default,,0,0,0,,{\an5\pos(192,144)\fscx90\fscy90\t(0,2500,\fscx120\fscy120)}And{\fscx100\fscy100} so my fellow Americans,
Dialogue: 0,0:00:2.50,0:00:05.00,Default,,0,0,0,,{\an5\pos(192,144)\fscx120\fscy120\t(0,2500,\fscx100\fscy100)}And{\fscx100\fscy100} so my fellow Americans,

this shows the video output.
https://youtube.com/shorts/d4VaoWqTMtQ?feature=share
Thanks in advanced.

You can split text to 2 lines: Dialogue: 0,0:00:0.00,0:00:02.50,Default,,0,0,0,,{\an5\pos(50,14)\fscx90\fscy90\t(0,2500,\fscx120\fscy120)}And
Dialogue: 0,0:00:0.00,0:00:02.50,Default,,0,0,0,,{\an5\pos(200,23)} so my fellow Americans,. Change \pos() values to fit. Why PlayResX PlayResY is not 720 1280?

This is a good idea, but measuring the text is very tricky.  Any suggestions for how to accurately measure the letters, and spaces to match where it naturally goes?  The PlayResX and PlayResY are being set by stable-ts, which is generating the ass file.  Maybe these are just defaults, but you're right, I will update to the input video.
